# Is it possible to display a frame during a CameraCapturetask on WP7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I would like to use the CameraCapturetask on my Silverlight WP7 application. On the background, I would like to display a photo, for example something like that : [image]

(found randomly on the web).

This could act as a mask, and we will see the photo of the camera behind this frame during the take of the photo.

(I'm not sure I'm very clear).

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't put this on top of the CameraCaptureTask.

You could add the border after the photo had been taken though.